# client.get("me/statuses") returns empty "data" array using C# Facebook SDK 5.0.3

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Using the C# Facebook SDK 5.0.3 everything works fine whit the client.Get("/me").

But when retrieving the status, I should get aan arraylist "data" with all the status messages according to the facebook Graph API, but instead my data array is empty and I get a 'Index out of bounds' exception.

Does anyone have an idea what my problem could be?

```
if (Request.Params["code"] != null)
            {

                var client = new FacebookClient(GetAccessToken());

                dynamic me = client.Get("/me");

                imgUser.ImageUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + me.id + "/picture";
                lblUsername.Text = me.name;
                lblHometown.Text = me.hometown.name;
                lblBirthday.Text = me.birthday;
                lblCurrenttown.Text = me.location.name;
                lblEmail.Text = me.email;
                lblOpleidingen.Text = "";
                lblOpleidingen.Text += me.education[1].type + ": " + me.education[1].school.name + ", " + me.education[1].year.name + "<br />"
                    + me.education[0].type + ": " + me.education[0].school.name + ", " + me.education[0].year.name;
                lblSex.Text = me.gender;

                dynamic status = client.get("/me/statuses");

                txtStatus.Text = status.data[0].message;
            }
```

Comment: The leading slash is unnecessary. Have you tried it without? Where are you getting the access token from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires the read_stream permission. Ensure you have it.

Your permission array should look like follows:

```
string[] extendedPermissions = new[] { "user_about_me", "read_stream" };

            if (extendedPermissions != null && extendedPermissions.Length > 0)
            {
                var scope = new StringBuilder();
                scope.Append(string.Join(",", extendedPermissions));
                parameters["scope"] = scope.ToString();
            }
```

furthermore your second get() should be capitalized: Get()

```
dynamic status = client.get("/me/statuses");

dynamic status = client.Get("/me/statuses");
```

Comment: I think JackNova is right. You probably forgot to use the right permission scope added while authenticating.